# Get all categories from a CategoryGroupModel through API

Tags: categories

When I get a CategoryGroup with the following

```
$category = craft()->categories->getGroupByHandle('productEnvironment');
```

I Just can't figure out how to get the categories inside this category.
Is-there any kind of relation/method ?

Thanks

Nicolas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that it was not the best way to to it.
I used the following code and it cleared my problem.

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Category);
$criteria->group = 'productEnvironment';
$entries = $criteria->find();

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo $entry->title . '<br>';
    echo $entry->mountingPreview[0] . '<br>'; // Dirty get the first assets
}
```

Hope this helps someone